# How do I make sure User input integer type only and integer that is greater than 0?

Tags: java, algorithm, integer

I am attempting to make sure the user input int type only and make sure the integer inputted is greater than `0`.

I was able to come up with the following to make sure the input is int type:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) 
{
    scanner.next();
}
int input = scan.nextInt();
```

But how should I include a condition checking to make sure the integer is greater than 0 as well?

Comment: You check the value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your current approach is you've already ready the value from the `Scanner` before it reaches `int input = scan.nextInt();`, meaning that by the time you use `nextInt`, there's nothing in the `Scanner` to be read and it will wait for the next input from user...

Instead, you could read the `String` from the `Scanner` using `next`, use `Integer.parseInt` to try and parse the result to an `int` and then check the result, for example...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int intValue = -1;
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter a integer value greater than 0: ");
    String next = scanner.next();
    try {
        intValue = Integer.parseInt(next);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
    }
} while (intValue < 0);

System.out.println("You input " + intValue);
```

Comment: Does this check the User input is of type Integer?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` will do it's own internal checking, throwing an `Exception` if the value can not be parsed to an `int` value.  You can not `read` and `check` for an `int` at the same time using `Scanner`

Comment: What does intValue = -1 represent?

Comment: In my example, `intValue` is initialised to `-1` so that it will cause `while (intValue < 0)` to be `true` if the user failed to enter a valid value...

Answer (score 0):

put an if statement inside your while loop like this

```
if(num <= 0){
   System.out.println("Enter a number greater than zero");
}
else{
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a condition in your code but not in the loop as.
`

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
abc: 
while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) 
{
    scanner.next();
}
int input = scan.nextInt();
if(input <= 0){
   goto abc;
}
```

`

Answer (score -1):

using .isDigit() method then checking to see if that number is greater than 0 if it is a digit